# What is the equivalent package for react-native-message-composer

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

What is the equivalent package for react-native-message-composer.

I have implemented react-native-message-composer. But it works for iOS while moving to Android it not worked.

I got  `Cannot read property 'composeMessageWithArgs' of undefined). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

[image]